# Sequences with integral variances

Tags: nt.number-theory, discrete-mathematics, integer-sequences

This is a companion to my earlier question,
[Sequences with integral means](https://mathoverflow.net/q/146733/6094).
This new question is, frankly, not as interesting, but it feels necessary to complete
the thought.

Let $V(n)$ be the sequence whose first element is $n$, and from then onward,
the next element is the smallest natural number ${\ge}1$ that ensures that the
variance of all the numbers in the sequence is an integer.
If there is no such number to extend $V(n)$, then it has finite length.

For example, for $n=20$, $V(20) = 20,2,2,4$.
When the last element $4$ is added, the mean is $28/4=7$, and the
variance sum is
$$13^2 + (-5)^2 + (-5)^2 + (-3)^2 = 169+25+25+9 = 228$$
which is divisible by $n=4$ yielding a variance of $57$.
(*NB*: An earlier version of this question divided by $n{-}1$ rather than by $n$; see the comments.)
None of the smaller alternatives $1,2,3$ lead to integral variance.
The $V(20)$ sequence cannot be extended beyond that terminating $4$,
for the attempt to extend leads to a quadratic Diophantine equation with no solution.

> **Q1**. Is it the case that the only infinite sequences are 
>   $V(1)=1,1,1,\ldots$ and
>   $V(2)=2,2,2,\ldots$ ?
>
> **Q2**. Is there nevertheless no upperbound on the length of the longest
>   finite sequence?

Here are some "long" sequences encountered within $n \le 1000$,
of lengths $6$, $6$, $8$, and $9$ respectively:
$V(61)=61,1,1,1,1,1$; $V(62)=62,2,2,2,2,2$;
$V(422)=422,2,2,2,2,2,2,6$;
$V(842)=842,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,8$.

Comment: Dividing by $n-1$, not by $n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, dividing by $n-1$. Of course one could define the variance differently, I was just following the typical unbiased estimate of the variance... Perhaps for number-theoretic interest, dividing by $n$ would be more natural?

Comment: Another unimpeachable source: the Kahn Academy! :-) [Review and intuition why we divide by n-1 for the unbiased sample variance](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/descriptive-statistics/variance_std_deviation/v/review-and-intuition-why-we-divide-by-n-1-for-the-unbiased-sample-variance).

Comment: Since this is not a situation of sampling from a distribution, I don't see what an "unbiased estimate" has to do with it.  You're free to use whatever formula you want, but you should at least specify it.

Comment: Division by $n-1$ is used for an unbiased estimate of the *population* variance---but what is the "population" here? Division by $n$ is more natural in this case. (If we do have a "population" in mind, division by $n$ gives the maximum-likelihood estimate for its variance, also a natural quantity.)

Comment: @RobertIsrael & JohnBentin & GerryMyerson: You are right; I have changed the variance to divide by $n$. I came upon this problem from a sampling context, but that context is left so far behind in the problem formulation that it doesn't make sense to divide by $n{-}1$. Thanks.

Comment: Small typo: Your $(32)^2$ should be $(-3)^2$.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke How about the sequences arising from the elements in http://oeis.org/A174554? I believe this will answer your second question (there is no upper-bound as one can produce a long string of $2$s).

Comment: @BenjaminDickman: Very nice! E.g., $27722, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2$: length $12$. And for each of those, start with $n-1$: $27721, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1$.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Is it the case that this sequence always matches the sequence of means until it terminates?  If that is always the case, then it would follow that the sequence of variances must terminate.

Comment: (@Lucia: Sorry, cannot reply now...)

Answer (score 3):

The variance of the list $n,1,1,\dots,1$ of length $k$ equals $(k-1)(n-1)^2/k^2$. In particular, if $n\equiv1\pmod k$ then this variance is an integer. It follows that if $n\equiv1\pmod{k!}$, then the sequence $V(n)$ has length at least $k$. This answers Q2: there is no upper bound on the length of such sequences.