# Why does this sequence converges to $\pi$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

One of my daughters was having a small programming exercise.

Let's consider following algorithm:

- Take a list of length $n$: $\ (1\,\ 2\,\ \ldots\,\ n)$.
- Remove every $2$nd number.
- From the resulting list, remove every $3$rd number.
- From the resulting list, remove every $4$th number.
- ... Follow on until the list remains unchanged and let $u_n$ be the number of remaining elements.

Example with $n=11$

- $(\ 1\,\ 2\,\ 3\,\ 4\,\ 5\,\ 6\,\ 7\,\ 8\,\ 9\,\ 10\,\ 11\ )\quad \Rightarrow\quad (\ 1\ *\ 3\ *\ 5\ *\ 7\ *\ 9 \ *\ 11\ )$
- $(\ 1\,\ 3\,\ 5\,\ 7\,\ 9\,\ 11\ )\quad \Rightarrow\quad (\ 1\,\ 3\ *\ 7\,\ 9\ *\ )$
- $(\ 1\, 3\,\ 7\,\ 9\ )\quad \Rightarrow\quad (\ 1\,\ 3\,\ 7\ *\ )$
- $(\ 1\,\ 3\,\ 7\ )\ $ -- will not be modified anymore, and therefore $u_n=3$.

**QUESTION:**   why do we have $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n}{u_n^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose $4$ in the right-hand side of the first line of the example was supposed to be cancelled, too?

Comment: Yes and it is... the issue is that the strikethrough bar is just on the bar of the $4$ number, leading to a poor readability.

Comment: Fixed (easy does it).

Comment: You don't need any integers in your sequence. Instead, you may have simply, say, $n$ stars $\ (*\ *\ \ldots\ *),\ $ etc.

Comment: Thus you do not need even any stars. You start with $\ c(n\ 1) := n.\ $ Then you define $\ c(n\ k) := c(n\ k\!-\!1)-\lfloor\frac {c(n\ k\!-\!1)}k\rfloor.\ $ Etc.

Comment: There must a definition of $\ \log(2)\ $ in similar spirit. I'd like to see it :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This problem was studied first by the founder of sieve theory, Brun himself, who proved this asymptotic.  For a fairly recent paper on this subject look at [Andersson](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa85/aa8542.pdf) who gives more precise estimates for $u_n$.  The MO question [Sequences with integral means](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146733/sequences-with-integral-means/146849#146849) is also closely related, and see also my answer there.

Comment: See also OEIS sequence A000960 ( http://oeis.org/A000960 ) and references there.

Answer (score 5):

This is an extended comment: Interestingly enough, displaying the differences of consecutive terms of A000960 shows an amazing degree of fluctuation.[image]