# why this procedure grows asymptotically to $n^2/\pi$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series

Consider a natural number, say $n$.

Find the first number which is greater than or equal to $n$ and is a multiple of $n-1$.

Again find a number which is greater than or equal to this number and is a multiple of $n-2$.

Do this iteratively until a multiple of $2$ occurs and call the last number $x$.

(More formally: define numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ where $a_1 = n$ and $a_{k+1}$ is the least number greater than or equal to $a_k$ that is a multiple of $n-k$. Put $x = a_n$.)

....

I want to prove that $x$ is asymptotic to $n^2/\pi$.

.....

It's easy to see that $x$ is greater than $n^2/4$ because the first half of procedure can be determined and it achieves $n^2/4$ but the proof must be much harder...

Can somebody help me?

Thanks...

Comment: Do you have any numerical results? If yes. then it it will be nice to see them in your question. See for example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146733/sequences-with-integral-means or http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193933/why-does-this-sequence-converges-to-pi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is proved by [Kevin Brown](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath001/kmath001.htm). The numbers are tabulated, and many links and references given, at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A002491).